# How can we auto refresh a page which is not a default page

Tags: asp.net

How can we auto refresh a page which is not a default page?

Suppose I have a site in which I want to send a mail to all the subscribed Email id's when any product is added in the site (page- "New_News). Now the problem is that my default page is homepage and how can I set auto refresh to that particular page i.e. "New_News".

I have searched a lot over this, but every result I have found to refresh on page_load not an individual page of the site.

If anyone have an idea kindly share to me.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean by auto-refresh! Also as such, `refresh on page_load ` method would work for all pages (and not only home page) because every aspx page can have `page_load` event handler!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose i have a 30 pages in the site & home page is default page. Now how  can I auto refresh a "new_news" name page (one of the 30 page) or check on every 5 minute to that page. Now the issue is that by default I set "Home page" as default page. So "new_news" is not hit until i run this.

Comment: Get current url and check if it is new_news.aspx then add resrefh header. string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; Page.Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "your seconds here; URL=new_news.aspx");

Comment: Thanks Kad1r ! Can u write in new solution so that i it could be easy for me.

Comment: @John, I am sorry but I am not sure of what exactly you want? But assuming that you want to inform the user of any data change on the server regardless of any page he is on currently, you would need a common start-up java-script that would make periodic AJAX call to server for checking any data-change and if any then will inform user and optionally navigate him to the updated data page (would be new_news if my assumption is correct)

Comment: VinayC read my above comment. I hope that makes a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this. The only way is create Window Services & hit page for particular time. Below is wonderful link for creating Window Service that helps me a lot:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html